# Set initialState With Value from Custom Use Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I update currentRuns when the request in useRuns finishes and runs is updated?

Issue

- currentRuns is initially set with an empty array (initial state for runs in useRuns)
- currentRuns is not updated when useRuns finishes
- Since currentRuns is an empty array, runTable displays nothing
- Ideally, currentRuns initial state is updated when useRuns's runs is updated

Runs.ts

```
function useRuns(count: number) {

    const [runs, setRuns] = useState<IRun[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getRuns = async () => {
            try {
                const runs = await request<IRun[]>(... request specifying count ...)
                setRuns(runs)
            } catch (error) {
                ... error logging ...
            }
        }
        getRuns()
    }, [count])

    const runsSummary = useMemo(() => { 
       ... calculate run summary ... 
    }, [runs])

    const runTuple: [IRun[], IRunsSummary] = [runs, runsSummary]
    return runTuple
}
```

LogViewer.tsx

```
function LogViewer() {
    const [runs, runsSummary] = useRuns(runCount);
    const [currentRuns, setCurrentRuns] = useState<IRun[]>(runs)

    const addFilter = (columnName: keyof IRun) => (value: string | string[]) => {
        const filteredRuns = runs.filter(run => {
            ... filter logic ...
        })
        setCurrentRuns(filteredRuns)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            ... other components that use addFilter ...
            <RunTable runs={currentRuns} />
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've mainly tried logging statements to ascertain what seems to be going on.

Hypothetically, I could pass runs into runTable and move the filtering logic into RunTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any information about the implementation of `RunTable` component, that's why I can't confidently give advice about moving  filtering logic into the `RunTable` component, but what I'm sure about is that you can easily sync `currentRuns` with `runs` using `useEffect` hook inside `LogViewer` component like this:

```
  const [runs, runsSummary] = useRuns(runCount);
  const [currentRuns, setCurrentRuns] = useState<IRun[]>(runs)

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentRuns(runs)
  }, [runs.length])
```